# Filter ip, method and other

Tags: filter, wireshark

i'm trying to filter out the ip, the method(GET and POST), and then http data that contains a specific string. The filter looks like this:

```
http.request.method == "GET" && http.request.method == "POST" && ip.src == 10.1.5.8 && http contains "facebook"
```

I want to filter the data as specified by the filter, but it don't work. If I use || instead of &&, it works, other IPs are also shown, which is wrong. The only IP that should be listed is 10.1.5.8

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
(http.request.method == "GET" or http.request.method == "POST") and (ip.src == 10.1.5.8 or ip.src == 10.1.5.2 or ip.src == 10.1.5.3 or ip.src == 10.1.5.4 or ip.src == 10.1.5.5 or ip.src == 10.1.5.7) and (http contains "facebook" or http contains "reddit")
```